# Download button in text Quarto

Tags: button, text, download, quarto

I would like to have a download button in the middle of a sentence to a pdf or csv document for example. This means there should be a small button in the sentence suggesting that you can download a document, not in a navigation or side bar. Here is some reproducible code:

```
---
title: "Download button in text Quarto"
format: 
  html:
    code-fold: true
engine: knitr
---

I would like to have a download button [here]() for pdf or CSV document for example.
```

I am not sure if it is possible to implement a clean button in a sentence using [`downloadthis`](https://fmmattioni.github.io/downloadthis/index.html) package because it should be in the middle of a sentence with text around.

Comment: You may want to check out the updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

I have create quarto shortcode extension [`downloadthis`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/downloadthis) that provides a [shortcode](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/shortcodes.html) to embed a download button more easily (in comparison to my old answer) and doesn't require to use an R package (but of course, this extension is inspired by [`{downloadthis}`](https://fmmattioni.github.io/downloadthis/index.html))

So after installing that shortcode, we can use the shortcode as following,

```
---
title: "Download button in text Quarto"
format: 
  html:
    css: style.css
engine: knitr
---

The following button is a download button for matcars data {{< downloadthis mtcars.csv
label="Download data" dname=mtcars id=mtcars-btn >}}  You can download the mtcars data as csv file by clicking on it.
```

**style.css**

```
#mtcars-btn {
     font-size: xx-small;
     padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem !important;
   }

#down-btn {
 margin-right: 2px;
 margin-left: 2px;
}

a:has(#mtcars-btn) {
 text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

[image: demo screenshot of using shortcode]

Explore [here](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/downloadthis#using) for more options and live demos.

---

#### Old Answer

Using a bit of CSS and javascript, it is possible to do very easily.

````
---
title: "Download button in text Quarto"
format: 
  html:
    code-fold: true
    include-after-body: add_button.html
engine: knitr
---


```{r}
#| echo: false

library(downloadthis)

mtcars %>%
  download_this(
    output_name = "mtcars dataset",
    output_extension = ".csv",
    button_label = "Download data",
    button_type = "default",
    self_contained = TRUE,
    has_icon = TRUE,
    icon = "fa fa-save",
    id = "mtcars-btn"
  )
```


The following button is a download button for matcars data <span id="down-btn"></span> You can download the mtcars data as csv file by clicking on it.
````

**add_button.html**

```
<style>
   #mtcars-btn {
     font-size: xx-small;
     padding: 0.2rem 0.3rem !important;
   }
   
   #down-btn {
     margin-right: 2px;
     margin-left: 2px;
   }
   
   a:has(#mtcars-btn) {
     text-decoration: none !important;
   }

   #mtcars-btn:focus,
   #mtcars-btn:active  {
      box-shadow: none !important;
   }
   
   #mtcars-btn:hover {
     transition: 0.2s;
     filter: brightness(0.90);
   }
   
   #mtcars-btn:active {
     filter: brightness(0.80);
   }
   
</style>


<script>
  function add_button() {
    /* get the R generated button by its id */
    let mtcars_btn = document.querySelector("a:has(#mtcars-btn)");
    mtcars_btn.href = '#mtcars-btn';
    
    /* get the placeholder where you want to put this button */
    let down_btn = document.querySelector("span#down-btn");
    
    /* append the R generated button to the placeholder*/
    down_btn.appendChild(mtcars_btn)
  }
  
  window.onload = add_button();
</script>
```

---

[image: download button embeded in paragraph]

---

### Explanation

So what I have done here

- At first, created a download button using the [`downloadthis`](https://fmmattioni.github.io/downloadthis/index.html) with an `id=mtcars-btn` so that we can get hold of this generated button with js code using this `#mtcars-btn` id selector
- Then created a placeholder inside the paragraph text using `<span></span>`, where I want the download button to be and also in this case, assigned an id `down-btn` to that `span`, so that we can target this `span` using `#down-btn`.
- Then using js, simply appended that generated download button to placeholder `span` tag so that the button is in the place where we wanted it to be.
- Lastly, used some css to make this button smaller, reduced button padding, created a bit left and right margin and removed the underline.

Thats it!